# setting minHeight in CollapsingToolbarLayout not having any effect

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, material-design, android-toolbar

The main problem I've currently got with the CollapsingToolbarLayout is, that whatever I'm trying, the minHeight attribute of my Toolbar does not have any effect.

My desired result would be this:
(The CollapsingToolbarLayout with a certain expanded height and a certain collapsed height (in the example 180dp), while the title either collapses or stays on the top)

[image]

But whatever I do, the title sometimes is in the center, won't completely collapse or the minHeight is ignored anyway. I have tried to set the minHeight for either AppBarLayout, CollapsingToolbarLayout, the toolbar itself, any contents, etc. also with different approaches found on the web but with no luck.

Here is the basic xml:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:minHeight="180dp">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="@android:color/transparent"
            app:expandedTitleGravity="bottom"
            app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearence.App.ToolbarTitle"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:statusBarScrim="@android:color/transparent">

            <com.xxxxxx.custom.Banner
                android:id="@+id/parallax_image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/xxxxxxxx"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.6"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:minHeight="180dp"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

I hope this is enough content to explain my problem.
Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the height to `180dp` instead of using minHeight, and then add a TextView into the toolbar to serve as the title.

Comment: with some tweaks by adding a custom TextView as title it worked. I could not get it working with expanding or collapsing toolbar anyway though...

Comment: Where did `180dp` come from?

Answer (score 18):

This one is pretty easy. Just set bottom margin of your `Toolbar` to whatever space you want to be reserved in the collapsed version.

The reasoning behind this is simple. `CollapsingToolbarLayout` inherits from `FrameLayout` which stacks images on top of each other. The only things it takes in account when considering collapsed bounds are toolbar height and its top / bottom margins.

Comment: Worked like a charm, thank you so much for the extra time spent explaining the answer!

Answer (score 1):

just set Toolbar collapseMode as "pin" mode, and height with your requirement size

```
 <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>
```